# ADC IC I2C problem

Tags: integrated-circuit, adc, i2c, pullup, 3.3v

I'm trying to run ads7924 using stm32f series.

But i2c does not work so I check the i2c line.

Between 0R, MCU side 3.3V but ads7924 side 0V. I set pull up setting of MCU internally .

What is the problem? below is the circuit i designed
[image]

Comment: If you have 3.3V at the MCU end of the SDA line, and 0 V at the ADC, you must have a broken connection (open circuit) between the MCU and ADC.

Comment: Is 0R a zero ohm resistor? If so, you cannot have different voltages on each side.

Comment: I see no ground connection on MCU side. Is MCU ground connected to ADS7924 DGND?

Comment: "I set pull up setting of MCU internally" the internal MCU pull-ups are nowhere even close to the I2C slew requirements

Comment: Annie - yes.. its 0R. I designed it to debug point..

Comment: Peter Bennett = Yes.. that is the point that I can not understand.. I will check circuit again somewhere connedted

Comment: glen_geek5 - yes. AGND, DGND and MCU use the same GND.

Comment: Maple - So you mean, does i2c line connect pull up resistor externally?

Comment: The STM32F is running stable (without stop/standby/sleep modes) and internal pull-ups are set? Also take into account that the processor can go into a sleep mode (depending on the firmware or other Stop modes) and thereby switch off the pull-ups or switch on/off its own pull-up/down at ST32F when sleeping. IMHO it would be better for the I2C bus to connect the pull-ups externally.